# Create bootable syslinux USB on UEFI

Tags: linux, centos, uefi, boot-loader, syslinux

We use a Centos 8 machine to create syslinux bootable USB installers for our product. The created USB now supports only target machines with BIOS (or with CSM mode turned on) but we need to update it to support UEFI.

The [instructions on syslinux.org](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Install#UEFI) are pretty sparse and a few days of
searching have not been successful.

Trying to boot on a HP EliteDesk always results in "BootDevice not found". USB boot is enabled in the machine's BIOS.

**What we're doing**

1. Partition USB
2. Copy syslinux files
3. Copy syslinux.cfg
4. Run `syslinux` command to install

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong or perhaps a pointer to a better set of instructions on how to do this?

**PARTITION**

```
(parted) mkpart  
Partition name?  []? EFI 
File system type?  [ext2]? fat32 
Start? 512MB 
End? 1024MB 
(parted) set 1 esp 
New state?  [on]/off? on 
(parted) mkpart 
Partition name?  []? Installer 
File system type?  [ext2]? fat32 
Start? 1024MB End? 100% 
(parted) p 
Model: Generic Flash Disk (scsi) 
Disk /dev/sdc: 8053MB 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B 
Partition Table: gpt Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name       Flags
1      512MB   1024MB  513MB   fat32        EFI        boot, esp
2      1024MB  8052MB  7028MB  fat32        Installer
```

**COPY FILES**

After copying, the EFI partition contains:

```
# find /mnt/usb
/mnt/usb
/mnt/usb/efi
/mnt/usb/efi/boot
/mnt/usb/efi/boot/ldlinux.e64
/mnt/usb/efi/boot/syslinux.efi
/mnt/usb/efi/boot/libcom32.c32
/mnt/usb/efi/boot/vesamenu.c32
/mnt/usb/efi/boot/libutil.c32
/mnt/usb/efi/boot/menu.c32
```

**INSTALL SYSLINUX**

```
# umount /mnt/usb
# syslinux -d /efi/boot --install /dev/sdc1
```

**EDIT I**

I tried changing the file name based on the advice from [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) but the bootloader did not start. (was tried on an HP EliteDesk 800 and an industrial motherboard).

The HP machine says "BootDevice not found" and the industrial motherboard goes directly into the BIOS.

For testing, we're just trying to get the bootloader to be recognized.

BIOS Config: CSM is off and the boot device set to "UEFI: KIOXIA 1".

```
parted /dev/sdb p
Model: KIOXIA TransMemory (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      512MB  1024MB  513MB  fat32        EFI   boot, esp
```

The USB contains:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
[root@bluebox /]# cd /mnt/usb
[root@bluebox usb]# find .
.
./efi
./efi/boot
./efi/boot/bootx86.efi
./efi/boot/ldlinux.e64
./efi/boot/libcom32.c32
./efi/boot/libutil.c32
./efi/boot/menu.c32
./efi/boot/syslinux.cfg
./efi/boot/vesamenu.c32
[root@bluebox usb]# cd /
[root@bluebox /]# umount /mnt/usb
[root@bluebox /]# syslinux -d /efi/boot --install /dev/sdb1
[root@bluebox /]# echo $?
0
```

**EDIT II - SOLUTION**

The advice from [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom) was very close.  After renaming the path to **capital letters** syslinux now loads.

Specifically, on the USB `/efi/boot/bootx86.efi` must be `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx86.EFI`

**Reference Links**

- [Instructions on syslinux.org](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Install#UEFI)
- [Rods Books](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/syslinux.html)
- [Description of EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) at Wikipedia
- [Article on using `syslinux`](https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:slackware_admin:set_up_syslinux_as_boot_loader_on_uefi_based_hardware) for Slackware
- [Making a bootable USB](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/making-bootable-usb-using-syslinux/) by Harkamal Dadwal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On removable media, the UEFI boot file name for x86_64 architecture should be `\efi\boot\bootx64.efi`.

So in your case:

```
mv /mnt/usb/efi/boot/syslinux.efi /mnt/usb/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
```

Although the UEFI specification says the names should be case-insensitive, some UEFI implementations are known to have bugs here. So if this path does not work, you may have to try the upper-case version (`/mnt/usb/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI`) and see if it will work better.

Note that if Secure Boot is enabled, the firmware will mark all the memory allocated for files loaded by the bootloader as non-executable by the processor, unless the file is a Windows-style PE+ binary with a valid Secure Boot signature. The `ldlinux.e64` and `*.c32` files of Syslinux might not satisfy that requirement, as far as I know.

It seems the Syslinux project has no support for Secure Boot at all, so your boot media would only work with Secure Boot disabled.

Comment: Thanks!  I've tried your suggestion on two machines but so far no joy.  See the main question for the details.  Any other ideas?

Comment: On new systems, Secure Boot is typically enabled by default. On some systems, you cannot even disable it at all. Have you successfully disabled Secure Boot on the systems you have tested? When a boot file fails Secure Boot checks, a system may do one of two things: 1.) display a Secure Boot failure message, 2.) behave as if that boot option did not exist and proceed to the next available boot option, if any exists.

Comment: Do the BIOS configurations of the two test systems mention anything at all about Secure Boot? If there is no clear way to disable Secure Boot, there might be "Secure Boot key management" or something similar, and if it allows to clear the Secure Boot primary key (PK), that should also place the Secure Boot in "Setup Mode" which allows booting any EFI boot file - so clearing the PK would be effectively the same as disabling Secure Boot.

Comment: Secure boot is disabled on both machines I tried.  The HP machine goes into the UEFI diagnostics (not sure why) and the industrial motherboard just goes into the BIOS.  The industrial MB has no HDD attached so there is only one choice to boot from: USB. HP machine has the HDD disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: One idea: syslinux on my Centos 8 machine is 6.04, but doesn't include `syslinux.efi`.  I got `syslinux.efi` from Rod's books site.  I'll try reinstall whole thing again with everything 6.03.

Comment: I found the solution: path must upper case.  `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI`.  Edit your answer and I'll accept it :-)

Comment: According to the UEFI specification, that's a bug. It should be case insensitive. But it is already known that some UEFI implementations got it wrong. Looks like yours is one of them.