# How to install syslinux-efi64 on Centos 8

Tags: centos, yum, dnf

In order to [Create bootable syslinux USB on UEFI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/703920/create-bootable-syslinux-usb-on-uefi) with Centos 8, I need some files from the `syslinux-efi64` package.

The centos.org site says that [such a package exists](https://koji.mbox.centos.org/koji/rpminfo?rpmID=84767), but yum/dnf fails to install it:

```
dnf install syslinux-efi64
Last metadata expiration check: 0:19:04 ago on Sat 28 May 2022 06:18:38 PM +08.
No match for argument: syslinux-efi64
Error: Unable to find a match: syslinux-efi64
```

And `dnf search` says that "no matches were found".

I've searched a number of archive sites but also couldn't find an rpm to manually download and install...

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

After giving up on finding the syslinux-efi64 package I ended up compiling from source.

- get [source from kernel.org](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/syslinux-6.03.zip)
- compile with `make bios efi32 efi64 installer`
- install to build machine with: `sudo make install`
- copy EFI64 files (especially syslinux.efi) from `/usr/share/syslinux/efi64`